# Non malware use cases of LSASS dumping

Tags: windows

I recently looked up some techniques for dumping credentials from LSASS and came across an article that says PPL and other protections were not enabled by default in Windows because some non malicious programs from third parties (including antivirus companies) uses them.

However I was unable to find if actually some programs interact in a non-conventional way with LSASS, which programs do it and why.

Does anybody have information regarding this?

Comment: For people (like me) that don't recognise all TLAs and DETLAs(\*)...LSASS = [Local Security Authority Subsystem Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Security_Authority_Subsystem_Service), PPL = [Protected Process Light](https://www.scip.ch/en/?labs.20200116). (\*) DETLA = Double-Extended Three Letter Acronym.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be explicit: *dumping* anything out of LSASS is completely unsupported and is not ever taken into consideration when building LSA protection features.

What *is* taken into consideration is the public APIs that 3rd parties can use to load packages into LSA for Single Sign-On support. These APIs have been around forever and many ISVs have built genuine packages for their own software. Software like smart card middleware.

The way PPL works is by limiting what foreign code can be loaded into the LSA process by checking if the code is Authenticode-signed. It must have a special key usage and signed by a Microsoft CA before LSA will load it under PPL. So third parties *can* build packages that work with PPL, it's just effort on their part. Turning this requirement on overnight breaks that potentially mission-critical software and that's bad.

Requisite warning: when enabling PPL also enable HVCI for protection from potential kernel bypasses.

Comment: Thanks. Have you ever seen these ISVs not using the APIs? E.g. using thread injection or other "undocumented" methods to get their code running inside LSASS?

Comment: Do such implementations exist? Probably. Have I personally seen any? No, because it's unsupported and would have been a non-starter.